# wants to use eth0 instead of em1 and pXpY

Tags: ubuntu, syslinux

I am using Ubuntu server 13.10 and i am doing automated installation of Ubuntu server 13.10, After installation i wants to do network configuration automatically and for that i wants to put eth0 name as first network device and eth1 as second network device.

But recent motherboards and hardwares gives em1 for devices integrated in motherboard and give pXpY for devices connected to slots.

Now i did hardcode network device names on syslinux.cfg look like:

```
MENU LABEL Fresh Install With Format ^Ubuntu Server 13.10
    KERNEL /install/vmlinuz
    APPEND initrd=/install/initrd.gz biosdevname=0
```

But i am not sure is this work or not? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: eth# is going away and you should get accustomed to the change now.

Comment: Yeah its true but is there any way i can do this stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making sure that the boot-loader is configured to pass the necessary parameter to the kernel, just get rid of the feature altogether:

```
aptitude purge biosdevname && update-initramfs -u
```